# iOS: How to get the servicebundle headers for iOS 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

How do we get/dump the servicebundle headers for iOS 9 (especially the IncomingCall.servicebundle headers)?

There are published IncomingCall.servicebundle headers for older iOS versions (e.g. https://github.com/justzt/iPhone-IncomingCall.servicebundle-headers).

I'm trying for a while now to find or dump them for iOS 9 but had no luck. The classdump-dyld tool (as described at http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Reverse_Engineering_Tools#class-dump.2C_class_dump_z.2C_classdump-dyld) is not able to dump my dyld library as it is "Not a suitable image: dyld_shared_cache_arm64".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like here we have it (the link for which the question was intended): https://github.com/CPDigitalDarkroom/iOS9-SpringBoard-Headers/tree/master/System/Library/SpringBoardPlugins

(and here is something for iOS 9.1, but seems incomplete: https://github.com/GreenyDev/iOS9.1-SpringBoard-Headers)

Edit: I don't understand why my answer is eligible for deletion. The question was asked by me and I expected an answer just like this (a link to the servicebundle headers). Of course we can't post the headers here in stackoverflow. The question was "how/where to get". The addition "how to dump" to the question was meant only in case they are not available anywhere.

Comment: I don't understand why my answer is eligible for deletion. The question was asked by me and I expected an answer just like this (a link to the servicebundle headers). Of course we can't post the headers here in stackoverflow. The question was "how/where to get". The addition "how to dump" to the question was meant only in case they are not available anywhere.

Answer (score -3):

try  this

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request  queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse response, NSData data, NSError *connectionError) {

```
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        NSLog(@"response status code: %ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]);
    if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {


    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
        if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"X-Auth"]) {
            [userDefaults setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"X-Auth"]] forKey:@"X-Auth"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not even remotely answer the question.